# Google OAuth 2.0 blank screen after sign in

Tags: ubuntu, oauth-2.0, oauth, digital-ocean, production-environment

using MERN stack with refine
everything is fine in localhost but in production server it is blank after signing in, ive tried other hosting it works just fine, ive also add the right client id and Authorized JavaScript origins/Authorized redirect URIs,

i used ubuntu digital ocean server in http://167.172.236.212:3080
but Oauth require public top-level domain so i changed it with http://167.172.236.212.nip.io:3080 also tried
http://167.172.236.212.sslip.io:3080 but also not ow

[the renderer is working but not in ubuntu server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxDWU.jpg)
[Does the problem connected with the this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3AWd.png)